# Every Nth Element In Convolution

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a faster way to do `np.convolve(A, B)[::N]` using Numpy?  It feels wasteful to compute all the convolutions and then throw `N - 1` of `N` away...  I could do a for loop or list comprehension, but I thought it would be faster to use only native Numpy methods.

#### EDIT

Or does Numpy do lazy evaluation?  I just saw [this](https://remedajs.com/) from a JS library, would be awesome for Numpy as well:

```js
// Get first 3 unique values
const arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const result = R.pipe(
  arr,
  R.map(x => {
    console.log('iterate', x);
    return x;
  }),
  R.uniq(),
  R.take(3)
); // => [1, 2, 3]
  
/**
 * Console output:
 * iterate 1
 * iterate 2
 * iterate 2
 * iterate 3
 * /
```

Comment: Interesting question, would you provide a small test sample (how many dimensions do you have?)

Comment: Hi, my dimension is only one!  I wanted to try the discrete wavelet transform on some audio file, my understanding is that one convolves overlapping frames of the signal with the wavelet, which is much shorter than the signal.  So e.g. the wavelet has length `8` and I want to compute `np.convolve(signal, wavelet)[::4]`.

Comment: which convolution `mode` are you using? (`full`/`valid`/`same`?)

Comment: In my case `full`, but I would also be happy about a solution using a different mode, after all I can pad the array with zeros anyway.

Comment: OK and how does `N` compare to `B.shape[0]`?

Comment: In my case it would be `B.shape[0] // 2`.  The wavelet (`B`) would be of length `2**n` and the overlap is one half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convolution is a product of your kernel and a window on your array, then the sum. You can achieve the same manually using a rolling window:

First let's see a dummy example

```
A = np.arange(30)
B = np.ones(6)
N = 3

out = np.convolve(A, B)[::N]
print(out)
```

output: `[  0.   6.  21.  39.  57.  75.  93. 111. 129. 147. 135.  57.]`

Now we do the same with a rolling view, padding, and slicing:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

out = (swv(np.pad(A, B.shape[0]-1), B.shape[0])[::N]*B).sum(axis=1)
print(out)
```

output: `[  0.   6.  21.  39.  57.  75.  93. 111. 129. 147. 135.  57.]`

Intermediate sliding view:

```
swv(np.pad(A, B.shape[0]-1), B.shape[0])

array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       ...
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  0],
       [26, 27, 28, 29,  0,  0],
       [27, 28, 29,  0,  0,  0],
       [28, 29,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [29,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])


# with slicing
swv(np.pad(A, B.shape[0]-1), B.shape[0])[::N]

array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  0],
       [28, 29,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```